# Could not retrieve profile with SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, user-profile

I am using SharePoint Designer to retrieve user profile information and got this error:

`Could not retrieve profile schema from server, Make sure the profile store is properly configured.`

[image]

However, I can get profile information with PowerShell (after granting my permission for User Profile Service)

Can anybody point to me how to solve this? or any clues for this problem?

Comment: did you check the permission on the site collection? under which account you trying to create the workflow? Try wit site collection admin or farm admin account....also check the ULS logs/ event log for more clue?

Answer (score 1):

You should look in the SharePoint logfile. In my case the IIS Application Pool user did not have permissions on the searchservice database. After granting the user permissions it worked.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers here pointed me in the right direction when I had this issue, I do not recommend altering SQL permissions directly yourself.

SharePoint will do this for you if you do the following steps:

1. Go to Central Admin - Manage Service Applications
2. Highlight the Search Service Application
3. Click "Administrators" in the ribbon
4. Add your Web Application's Application Pool Account
5. Grant "Read (Diagnostic Pages Only)"
6. Click OK.

You should then be able to pull back Profile Properties in SharePoint Designer.

[image: fix]

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue facing and tried google various sites but no luck finallu i got the fix

- Change SQL database permissions on the search database. 
  It was erroring for me at first, then once we granted the exec_ permissions it was able to see the User Profiles dropdown items.